# How to store created date on clicking submit button

Tags: jsf

How can I get created date  and store it to Database when I click command button.

```
     <p:inputText id="diff" styleClass="daysNumber" value="#{dayDiffBean.diff}">
     <f:valueChangeListener value="#{vacatioBean.vacation.balanceDay}" />
     </p:inputText>
     <h:commandButton styleClass="sndbutton1" value="#{text['employee.send']}"
                action="#{vacationBean.addVac}" />
```

In Bean I have

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Date vEndDate;
private Date vStartDate;
private Date createdDate;
    private String isNobody;
Requestrelax vacation;
Employee e;
    private short balanceDay;


@EJB
VacationLocal vacations;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean.userId}")

    Integer userId;

@EJB
EmployeesLocal employees;



@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    System.out.println("0");
    vacation=new Requestrelax();
    e=employees.getEmployee(userId);
    vacation.setEmployee(e);


}

public void addVac(){
    System.out.println("1");
    System.out.println("____________" +createdDate);
    vacation.setCreatedDate(createdDate);

    vacations.addEmployeeVacation(vacation);

}

    public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public Employee getE() {
    return e;
}

public void setE(Employee e) {
    this.e = e;
}

public Requestrelax getVacation() {
    return vacation;
}

public void setVacation(Requestrelax vacation) {
    this.vacation = vacation;
}

public Date getvEndDate() {
    return vEndDate;
}

public void setvEndDate(Date vEndDate) {
    this.vEndDate = vEndDate;
}

public Date getvStartDate() {
    return vStartDate;
}

public void setvStartDate(Date vStartDate) {
    this.vStartDate = vStartDate;
}

public short getBalanceDay() {
    return balanceDay;
}

public void setBalanceDay(short balanceDay) {
    this.balanceDay = balanceDay;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}



 }
```

How can I get created date using backing bean when I try to print it on console it is show null
Any suggetions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Date` object is null because it is never initialized. You need to do:

```
Date createdDate = new Date();
```

This is also what gives `createdDate` the actual `Date` that is created as its value.

---

On a *small* tangent, I would suggest using a [**`Calendar`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) when dealing with dates. Partly because the `Date` API is mostly ***flawed*** and ***deprecated***.

`Calendar` is a [**`Singleton`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object that can be used as following:

```
Calendar createdDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

When creating this object it will use the current `Locale` and `TimeZone`, unless you specify otherwise.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer! I did like this way  javaCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    
      Date currenDate=Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
      System.out.println(currenDate);
     vacation.setCreatedDate(currenDate);

Comment: But when I store it to db its showing with time how can i do just show dates like 12/23/14

Comment: You should look into DateFormats, also depending on the type of DB you are using, you might have to convert it to a sql-type Date object before your jdbc

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Josef E.'s answer, I would also suggest using Joda Time because of how Java Date APIs are in previous versions of Java.

Fortunately, in Java 8 this issue has been fixed.